# MaxListenersExceededWarning Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected/multiple objects sent

Tags: node.js

I have this code. It is working as desired. On the webpage I see temp and pressure. But I have 2 issues. First is an error message

```
(node:10560) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 16 connection listeners added to [WebSocketServer]
```

I can avoid it by setting value of `defaultMaxListeners` to infinity but I want to know what is happening and why it is happening?

Second thing is that the client is receiving loads of objects with temp/pressure data. I set refreshing frequency to 1 sec. In the logs of the nodejs it is refreshing OK. In the browser I see something like in the picture attached. Also the question is why it produces so many objects while frequency is set to 1 second.

```js
var five = require('johnny-five');
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8085 });
var board = new five.Board({
  port: 'COM4',
});

board.on('ready', function () {
  var multi = new five.Multi({
    controller: 'BMP180',
    freq: 1000,
  });

  require('events').EventEmitter.defaultMaxListeners = 15;

  multi.on('change', function () {
    var temp = this.thermometer.celsius;

    var pressure = Math.round(this.barometer.pressure * 100, 1) / 10;

    var obj = {
      type: 'weather',
      press: pressure,
      temp: temp,
    };
    wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
      ws.send(JSON.stringify(obj));
    });
  });
});
```

[image]

Comment: The error you're getting means you have a memory leak. Setting your `defaultMaxListeners` to infinity does not fix this. In fact this would make it worse and will crash your computer as it runs out of memory eventually. From a quick glance at your code I would say that `wss.on('connection'` being nested inside `multi.on('change'` seems odd.

Comment: This error usually is caused by adding the same event handler over and over to a particular eventEmitter.  This causes them to build-up over time.  I don't know how the various events you have listeners for work, but you have nested listeners ready -> change -> connection.  So, if the `ready` event occurs more than once, you will be creating duplicate handlers for `change` and for `connection`.  If `change` occurs more than once, you will be creating duplicate handlers for the `connection` event.

Comment: The usual solution is to either move the event handler to a higher level (so you don't keep adding it over and over) or to switch to using `.once()` so an event handler removes itself after it fires.  My first guess would be that `wss.on('connection', ...)` should be at the top level so you never register it more than once.

Answer (score 0):

I had these issue using a promise callback (.then()) within the Socket.io event. That doesn't seem to be the issue for your case, as to no callback based stuff is done from your code.

Might be a hint for others reading this question after encountering the issue.